# Skein tree depth on a minimal knot or link diagram

Tags: knot-theory

The skein tree depth is the maximum length of the shortest path from a leaf to the root of a skein tree,  among all leaves. The skein tree depth of an oriented knot or a link $L$, denoted $td(L)$, is the minimum depth among all skein resolving trees for the knot or link. It gives a measure of the complexity of computing link polynomials by the skein relation.

Question: is $td(L)$ always realized on a minimal diagram for $L$?

I made some small computations and didn't find any counterexample. For example in: [image: 1]

we have a skein tree of depth $5$ for the knot $9n4$, and any other crossing gives us a depth at least $5$. From theory we know the lower bond of $2g$ that is $4$ for the knot. So is it possible for the knot to have a (non-minimal) diagram such that its resolving tree has depth $4$?